# Entity Framework - Why do I get optional dependent using table sharing?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am getting the following warning:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update: Warning: The entity of type 'Event.Description#RichText' is an optional dependent using table sharing. The entity does not have any property with a non-null value to identify whether the entity exists. This means that when it is queried no object instance will be created instead of an instance with all properties set to null values. Any nested dependents will also be lost. Either don't save any instance with only null values or mark the incoming navigation as required in the model. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the key values of the entity.

This is declared as:

```
public class Event
{
    public RichText? Description { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class RichText
{
    public string OpenXmlFilename { get; private set; }
    public string HtmlFilename { get; private set; }
    public string HtmlBody { get; private set; }
    public string Text { get; private set; }
    public RichText()
    {
        OpenXmlFilename = HtmlFilename = Text = HtmlBody = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is the warnings around this say I can't save a Description property where all of its properties are null. But I can't do that anyways as all of them are declared to not be null.

So why the warning? And is there an issue if I will never instantiate a `RichText` object with all null properties?

---

**Update:** Here's the config command:

```
public class EventConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Event>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Event> builder)
    {
        builder.OwnsOne(u => u.Description, desc =>
        {
            desc.Property(a => a.OpenXmlFilename).IsRequired();
        });
    }
}
```

---

As requested below, here's a part from TrackingDbContextModelSnapshot.cs

```
modelBuilder.Entity("LouisHowe.core.Models.Event", b =>
    {
        b.OwnsOne("LouisHowe.core.Models.RichText", "Description", b1 =>
            {
                b1.Property<int>("EventId")
                    .HasColumnType("int");

                b1.Property<string>("HtmlBody")
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b1.Property<string>("HtmlFilename")
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b1.Property<string>("OpenXmlFilename")
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b1.Property<string>("Text")
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b1.HasKey("EventId");

                b1.ToTable("Events");

                b1.WithOwner()
                    .HasForeignKey("EventId");
            });
```

Comment: This specific error is mentioned as a [breaking change in EF Core 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/breaking-changes#nested-optional-dependents-sharing-a-table-and-with-no-required-properties-are-disallowed), which explains both the `Why` and how to fix this.  The change description implies there's missing important information in the query too - both `Event` and `RichTextBox` are `Owned` and `Event` has more nullable properties too

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But in my case `RichText` has no nullable properties. So it provides an easy way to determine if `RichText` is null. What am I missing in that?

Comment: Why do you use these strings in configuration? Use generics and lambda expressions and you'll see what's wrong.

Comment: @GertArnold I don't understand. Do you mean in the file TrackingDbContextModelSnapshot.cs? That file is created by EF when I run " Add-Migration InitialCreate" so I have no control over what it emits.

Comment: Ah yes, of course. But then where's the code that tells EF that `RichText` is an owned type? You must have configured that. By default, EF would assume that both classes need a table of their own and require `RichText` to have a key property.

Comment: @GertArnold Oops, sorry. I thought I had listed that - but hadn't. Added now. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what is causing this and put this in the category of very badly written error messages.

I had a bug in my code where, on an update, `Event.Description` was created with all null properties. All the properties are declared as non-null but that is not enforced. (As I said, a bug.)

So it then goes to update the record and EF is given a value that will write the `Event.Description` columns, but with nulls so on the next read `Event.Description` will be viewed as null.

Definitely a problem and EF is good to call it out. Once I understood the issue then the warning made sense. But before I knew what was going on, I read it as it could not figure out if `Event.Description` was null if saved with non-null values.

Answer (score 0):

While instantiating object `Event`, EF Core is trying to understand when assign `Description` to `null` and when create `RichText` with all properties. When all properties are nullable it сan't make a clear decision for that.

Schematically (just for explaining) EF Core will create the following mapper from `DbDataReader` for querying `Event`:

```cs
(DbDataReader r) => new Event
{
    Description = new RichText
    {
        OpenXmlFilename = r.IsDBNull(0) ? null : r.GetString(0),
        HtmlFilename = r.IsDBNull(1) ? null : r.GetString(1),
        HtmlBody = r.IsDBNull(2) ? null : r.GetString(2),
        Text = r.IsDBNull(3) ? null : r.GetString(3)
    }
};
```

So `Description` is not null, but all properties are null.

Having at least one not nullable field will help EF Core to make a decision.

```cs
(DbDataReader r) => new Event
{
    Description = r.IsDBNull(4) ? null 
        : new RichText
        {
            OpenXmlFilename = r.IsDBNull(0) ? null : r.GetString(0),
            HtmlFilename = r.IsDBNull(1) ? null : r.GetString(1),
            HtmlBody = r.IsDBNull(2) ? null : r.GetString(2),
            Text = r.IsDBNull(3) ? null : r.GetString(3),
            NotNullableField = r.GetString(4)
        }
};
```

Comment: That's why I'm asking - **every** property in `RichText` is non-nullable. If they were all nullable, this warning would make sense. But with none, then why do I get this? TIA

Comment: Show migration pat of Event table.

Comment: I added what I think you are asking for. If you need something else, please let me know. TIA